# Java Static class for saving middle variables

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I create a middle class save many variables in it, example:

```
public static class Middle{
    public static List<Student> listStudent = new ArrayList<>();
    public static String level = 1; (this example of level of a character in the game)
}
```

And assign value for those variables

```
class A{
    Middle.listStudent = GetData();
    Middle.level++;
    
    Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

And then in next class (or activity) we using those variables with new data

```
class B{
    ShowResult(Middle.listStudent);
    ShowResult(Middle.level);
}
```

I using this way because don't want to transfer data by Intent.

My question is, can we using this way too much in the whole application without getting any issue, and if the **middle class** it shut down for any reason, makes losing data?

Comment: No.  Using a single object to store all your data as global statics will make your program very hard to maintain and debug.  This kind of technique was popular up until about 50 years ago.  Please don't teach yourself to program this way.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem and why would this make the program hard to maintain and debug?

Answer (score 1):

1. If some static class become shutdown, maybe some serious error
   occurs in your application.The JVM had to exit.
2. In multithreading environment,this way can cause dirty read and
   brings into some strange thing.

You can try the code below. And see what's going on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create three threads to run it
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        //simulate multi-threaded environment
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                StaticData.listStudent.add(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + j);
                StaticData.level++;
            }
        }).start();
    }

    //show the last result , in single thread ,result must be 30 31 ,but maybe not this in multi-threaded environment
    System.out.println("Total Result listStudent's size is :" + StaticData.listStudent.size());
    System.out.println("Total Result level is :" + StaticData.level);

}

public static class StaticData {
    public static List<String> listStudent = new ArrayList<>();
    public static Integer level = 1;
}
```